# Google Maps API (for Business) - Geocoding and Address Formatting

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I am trying to tackle the issue saving/caching results for a Google Maps address look-up. As an example, I would start with the following address:

> Via della Resistenzo 3, 22070 - APPIANO GENTILE

If I enter that on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com), I get this response:

> Did you mean:
>   Via della Resistenza, 3, 22070 Appiano Gentile Como, Lombardia, Italy

When I click the link for the corrected address, it places marker "A" on the map. If I click marker "A" in the left-hand results area, it displays an info window with a correctly formatted address (including line breaks):

> Via della Resistenza, 3
>   22070 Appiano Gentile CO, Italy

Also in the left-hand results area is this:

> At this address:
>   Dedar Spa‎ -

If I click the link for Dedar Spa, it shows the business marker.

---

I would like to provide a similar experience on my web site:

1. User enters the address into a `textarea` on a form, and searches
2. If there are a list of suggested addresses, a suggested address could be selected, replacing `textarea` value with an address that includes the line breaks
3. If there are any "At this address:" values, one could be selected

---

**What I know:**

1. I can look up addresses using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/)
2. I can look up places using the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)

**What I don't know:**

1. How I get the properly formatted address with line breaks? The `formatted_address` values I've seen returned by the API do not have line breaks.
2. What values do I need to save from Google Places? How do I use those values when placing a marker with an infowindow on the map?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem number 1?

Comment: I never did find a solution for this. I haven't worked on it in some time.

Comment: That's comforting... :) well If I manage to solve it I'll post it here. Thanks.

Comment: @AJC - If you post a solution for #1, I will accept it.